# How to use two different adapters at the same time in Ember.js application?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I'm using basic adapter for one API:

```
App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
    revision: 12,
    adapter: DS.BasicAdapter.create()
});
```

Lets say I need to retrieve some data from an other service but using REST API:

```
App.Store2 = DS.Store.extend({
    revision: 12,
    adapter: DS.RESTAdapter.create()
});
```

How to use `store2` then? Or is there another approach to solve issue like this?

Answer (score 3):

You can add two different adapters, no need to create multiple stores.

For Ember 2:

> Model-specific adapters can be created by putting your adapter class in an app/adapters/ + model-name + .js file of the application.

Source: [DS.Adapter Class](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Adapter.html)

Answer (score 2):

When you need to use a different Store, define your Store and then specify the Model you want to retrieve:

```
App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
  revision: 12,
  adapter: DS.BasicAdapter.create()
});

App.store2 = DS.Store.create({
  revision: 12,
  adapter: DS.RESTAdapter.create()
});

// retrieving from custom store
var myModelObject = App.store2.find(App.MyDifferentModel, 1);

// retrieving from defaultStore is implicit for the Models defined
var post = App.Post.find(1);
```

hope it helps

Comment: but when mapping API to the model how I can tell it to use different store? Like: `var Post = DS.Model.extend({title: DS.attr('string')});` etc.

Comment: What's the significance of the `revision: 12`, seems kinda odd to track version like this.

Comment: I tried the above solution(App.store2) but it did not work in current Ember (ember.js 1.5.1, ember-data.js 1.0.0-beta.8). @intuitivepixel

Comment: this also doesnt work for me, getting error `Cannot read property 'lookupFactory' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'lookupFactory' of undefined` when i reference store2

Comment: I too was looking to do something similar; but from what I can tell, this is not working anymore. The model created by __store2__ will be put on the pending save queue; when the queue is run, it will be given a chance to find a __model__ specific adapter; else it will use the fallback adapter. The code is pretty clear in `https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/system/store.js#L2141`. You could try to overwrite the `adapterFor` method of your custom store however (not sure if it will work tho).

Answer (score 0):

This is how I made the above example work, note Im using `ember-cli`.
Instead of creating my store with the `DS.RESTAdapter.create()`, or in my case, Im using `DS.LSAdapter`, I create my store in a initializer like this:

```
app.LsStore = DS.Store.extend({
  adapter: '-ls',
});

app.register('store:lsstore', app.LsStore);
app.register('adapter:-ls', DS.LSAdapter);
```

This basically registers a `lsstore` and a `adapter:-ls` on the container. Then I can inject my store into the application's `route` or `controller`, and this will try to find the adapter using `adapter:-ls`.